# 20.04 fails to authenticate Wifi (Realtek RTL8723BE)

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, realtek

I found some similar questions with answers however they all lead to deprecated Gits or were for previous versions of the kernel.

I have a relatively fresh Ubuntu 20.04 install on Intel x64 hardware. LAMP + GUI. I am attempting to get the Wifi to connect to the router (sitting right next to the box) however I am in an authentication loop. I have tried to connect to another wifi network and this fails in the same manner. I'm using WPA2 Personal and im 100% sure the password is correct!

I looked into installing specific RTL8723BE drivers but all the Gits are deprecated or have notes stating to use the default drivers.

I'm at a loss as to what to do next. Any help appreciated.

UPDATE: Thanks to suggestions below I have removed and re-added the adaptor and I still get consistent authentication failures in the GUI and CLI. Im convinced this is a driver issue as that's the only thing I haven't changed yet. Can anyone point me at a working replacement for the RTL8723BE?

```
Passwords or encryption keys are required to access the wireless network 'SSID'.
Warning: password for '802-11-wireless-security.psk' not given in 'passwd-file' and nmcli cannot ask without '--ask' option.
Error: Connection activation failed: (7) Secrets were required, but not provided.
root@machine:/etc/netplan# nmcli d --ask connect wlp2s0
Passwords or encryption keys are required to access the wireless network 'SSID'.
Password (802-11-wireless-security.psk): ••••••••••••••
Passwords or encryption keys are required to access the wireless network 'SSID'.
Password (802-11-wireless-security.psk): ••••••••••••••
Error: Timeout 90 sec expired.
Error: Connection activation failed: (0) No reason given.
```

Comment: You mentioned that you sit right next to it. How close? What is your signal strength? I had the same problem when my `RTL8723BE` driver was buggy. I had to sit very close to have at least 30% signal strength. And only then when I sat at a 1-meter distance from my router I was able to connect... What Kernel are you using? I also struggled with outdated drivers, so when I finally found the correct one I made a backup of it because I distro hop quite often...

Comment: @DanielVavrik thank you. OK, the router is literally sitting on top of this machine. Its wired to it but I need wireless to do some home automation hacking. The funny this in for *this* network, the signal strength shows zero. Thats why I tried setting up another wireless network (strong signal reported) as still could not connect with the same authentication issues present. 

You mentioned correct drivers. Im using the stock distro drivers as all my searches lead to Gits that are deprecated. What drivers are you using?

Comment: After remove and re-add of the adaptor, CLI reports signal strength -4dbm

Answer (score 0):

If you have the latest drivers you can try this.

Remove and reinsert the module with following setting:

```
sudo modprobe -rv rtl8723be
sudo modprobe -v rtl8723be ant_sel=2
```

This will usually set your Wlan interface down. So set it up again.

```
sudo ip link set <interface> up
sudo iw dev <interface> scan
```

You can make this persistent with these commands:

```
echo "options rtl8723be ant_sel=2" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/50-rtl8723be.conf
```

This setting + having the latest driver fixed my problems.

Comment: This has gotten me one step closer. Now at least nmcli is asking for a password (it wasnt before so i used the gui)

Unfortunately Im still in an authentication loop. Now at least its consistent across GUI and CLI. Im convinced its a driver issue as that's the only thing I haven't tried yet. Any help on locating a replacement would be greatly appreciated.